# Basic factors ruling out other factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing, factoring, primality-test

Let's say you have to find the factors of a number $x$. You check if $x$ is divisible by $2$, and so rule out any multiples of $2$. Then, you go to then next non-multiple of $2$ - $3$. $x$ is not divisible by $3$, so you can rule out any multiples of $3$, and so on and so forth. You move up to the next non-multiple of the already ruled out numbers. Is there a way to prove this?

The second question is if there is a way to prove that a number is not prime (especially for non-Mersenne primes) without actually factoring the number or doing something that would take as long as or longer than factoring the number.

Comment: To the first question: Yes, of course, and this goes to the _fundamental theorem of arithmetic_: All integers have a unique factorization, and if an integer $x$'s factorization is not a superset of the factorization of another integer $y$, then $y$ does not divide $x$. To the second question, of course! There are numerous primality tests out there, some deterministic and some not, which can prove a number composite. The decomposition of a number into factors not equal to 1 or itself constitutes a proof of compositeness.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist, perhaps I should be more specific about the second question: a proof that does not involve actually factoring the number. =) Thanks!

Comment: The answer is still yes, that's what primality tests are for. It is known that proving an integer prime is much (!) less expensive than actually offering a factoring. Primality tests out there are the famous Rabin-Miller, Lucas, Baillie-PSW, Lucas-Lehmer, Lucas-Lehmer-Reisel, ... The Rabin-Miller test will always declare $x$ prime if it's prime, and prove $x$ composite with probability $\ge 3/4$ if it's composite. The other 1/4 of the time it will falsely declare the composite $x$ as prime when it's not, which is why it's usually repeated until the probability of mistake falls abysmally low.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist, so if the Rabin-Miller test declares $x$ prime, than it is prime, but if it declares $x$ is composite, then you repeat the test several times until the probability of the number being composite is very near 100%. Okay. So how many times are we talking about to get the probability of mistake abysmally low?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist, oh, geesh. So, if I put a number in, then there are two outcomes: the test says it is prime, or the test says it is composite. If it says it is prime, there's a 3/4 chance of it *not* being prime, so we have to repeat the test. If it says composite at any point during the testing, then we know for certain it is composite, otherwise, there is a probability $1/4^n$, $n$ being the number of times the test is done, that the number is actually prime. Okay. What is a reasonable probability to assume the number *is* prime?

Comment: The cryptographic standard FIPS PUB 186-4 specifies 56 iterations for 2048-bit RSA keys, which corresponds to a probability of $1/4^{56}$, which is $2 \times 10^{-34}$, in other words stupidly low. You are more likely to win the lottery and be killed by an asteroid the same day than to pick a composite number that passes 56 Rabin-Miller tests with all "prime", so for all practical purposes the MR test after 56 iterations provides near-certainty of correctness.

Comment: You will benefit greatly from reading about [primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test), particularly about the [Fermat primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Fermat_primality_test).